# jquery ajax in php register form

Tags: php, jquery

I have a problem with my javascript function. I have a register form in which i used jquery ajax to check that entered username is used by another or not(by Checking database). after press submit button "validateMyForm()" -my javascript function- is called in which i validate inputs in it. my jquery ajax is in it too.(you can see my codes in following).
You know that if returned value of "validateMyForm()" function is true, form is posted(in normal way no with ajax way). i want to post my form if entered username don't match with any one and don't want to post if username is used by another. but when i press submit button, the function skips "$.post" section and returns true always.
Can you help me?

My PHP code is:

```
<form method="post" action="signup.php" önsubmit="return validateMyForm();" id="formtag">
    <input id="username" name="username" class="input-text" type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit1" id="register" value="Register" />
</form>
```

And my javascript function is:

```
function validateMyForm() {
    var returnedVal = true;
    //get username input text
    .
    .
    .
    $.post('ajax/checkUsername.php',{ username:username },function(data){
            //Checking that entered username is used by another person or no
            .
            .
            .
            if(is used by another)
                returnedVal= false;
            else
                ShowError;

    }, "json");

    return returnedVal;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you make an asynchronous call. So `true` is returned before the server send an respone for the post-request.

You have to use a callback function or show the response after your post-call finished.

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
    //validate your form here
    ...
    $.post("/ajax/checkUsername.php", {username: username}, function(data) {
        //check returned value and show response to the user
        ...
    });
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Like Tobiass said you have to wait for the return. What I would do is call you function via an input button (not submit) and then if it returns true THEN I would use javascript to submit the form.

Comment: Do you mean that i have to inset your offered code into:$(document).ready(function() {

Comment: if you want to. It was just an example how to work with ajax-requests.

Comment: But!!! I want to post form after username validation(on normal way). your last lines of code "event.preventDefault();return false;" is opposite of my idea.

Comment: Ok, so but why don't you check the username after the form was submitted? And if the username is taken render the form again fill in the post values. So you do not need ajax anywhere.

Comment: Just Ajax!!! OK.My problem is solved by 2 words in "$.post" that is:         "async: false".it is result of your help. I didn't know anything about asynchronous call. Thank you again.